# CSS: <div> with curved edges and centered text (horizontal & vertical centered)

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve something like shown below.

In the code, i am using fixed height and margin.

How do i achieve the same without the fixed height and margin? 
How do i center the text vertically?

Note: the white border between the div's is for illustration only.

[image]

Code:

```html
<style>
  .div{
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .bg-gray-left{
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  }
  .bg-gray-middle{
    border-radius:0px;
  }
  .bg-gray-right{
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  }
  .container{
    border:solid 1px gray;
    width: 485px;
  }
  .div:nth-child(1),.div:nth-child(2){
    border-right-color: white;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid
  }
</style>
<!-- <div class="container"> -->
<div class="div bg-gray-left">div 1</div>
<div class="div bg-gray-middle">div 2</div>
<div class="div bg-gray-right">div 3</div>
<!-- </div> -->
```

Comment: You could use some `padding` to get that.

Comment: I assume you mean that any of the 3 divs could be any height and you want the content of each to center vertically and each maintain the same height. Look into display:table and display:table-cell. Or flex, or grid if you want to write a bunch of fallbacks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need height to fix it centrally. Just add padding and remove the margin and it should create the effect you need.

```
.div{
    width:160px;
    background-color: gray;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dbnrvxkq/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use padding in this instance.

```html
<style>
  .div{
    width:160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: gray;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .bg-gray-left{
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  }
  .bg-gray-middle{
    border-radius:0px;
  }
  .bg-gray-right{
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  }
  .container{
    border:solid 1px gray;
    width: 485px;
  }
  .div:nth-child(1),.div:nth-child(2){
    border-right-color: white;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid
  }
</style>
<!-- <div class="container"> -->
<div class="div bg-gray-left">div 1</div>
<div class="div bg-gray-middle">div 2</div>
<div class="div bg-gray-right">div 3</div>
<!-- </div> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding is lame.  It's only ever a matter of time before the size of something changes, or something takes multiple lines, or anything at all goes wrong, and then padding will no longer do what you want.  Using flex center is much more reliable:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Center anything
</div>
```

This will require you to either wrap all your items in a container, or work along a single axis (flex-direction: row or column), but it's really the most simple way to keep everything totally centered.